# How to create the wix blog draft post by using wix api and the wix api access token

Tags: api, post, blogs, velo

```
{
  "draftPost": {
    "title": "abc1",
    "richContent": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "type": "paragraph",
          "text": "This is a paragraph of text."
        },
        {
          "type": "paragraph",
          "textData": {
            "text": "This is a paragraph of text."
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "paragraph",
          "style": {
            "paddingTop": "20px"
          },
          "textData": {
            "text": "This is a paragraph of text."
          }
        } 
      ]
    }
  },
  "publish": false
}
```

I had tried to create the wix blog draft post with the above code
By the way, only the title had been created, but the description had not been created
What is the reason?
Please let me know the solution with the detailed example
Thanks

I want to know the detailed way to create the wix blog post with the wix api

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that paragraphs are containers, not texts themselves.

This means that you need to add a text node within a paragraph to actually display text. There are only a few examples of this in the documentation: https://dev.wix.com/api/rest/wix-blog/blog/draft-posts/list-draft-posts

For example:

```json
{ "draftPost": {
    "title": "abc1",     
    "richContent": {
        "nodes": [ {
            "type": "PARAGRAPH",
            "id": "",
            "nodes": [            {
              "type": "TEXT",
              "id": "",
              "nodes": [],
              "textData":               {
                "text": "This is a paragraph of text.",
                "decorations": []
              }
            }],
            "paragraphData":             {
              "textStyle": {"textAlignment": "AUTO"},
              "indentation": 0
            }
         } ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: By any chance do you know how to add an image in this request?